# Tailwind CSS: `peer-[:nth-of-type(3)_&]:block` ,what does it means?

Tags: tailwind-css

currently I learn [Tailwind CSS](https://www.tailwindcss.cn/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states), `peer-[:nth-of-type(3)_&]:block`,I don't understand the meaning of this selector.

For example: this is a piece of html code,

```
<input type="text" class="peer" placeholder="1"/>
<div class="block peer-[:nth-of-type(3)_&]:block">
                <p class="">fasdfasaf</p>
                <p>545235</p>
</div>
<input type="text" class="peer" placeholder="2"/>
<input type="text" class="peer " placeholder="3"/>
```

How to design sibling nodes to make the two html elements  `<p class="">fasdfasaf<p> <p>545235</p>` **visible**?, that is, remove the hidden of its parent element.

[This is the way I thought it would be displayed, the result is that it is not displayed, like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivVFQ.png)

[This is what I think the code should look like after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNrBZ.png)

Comment: The above is wrong and the correct one is:<div class="hidden  peer-[:nth-of-type(3)_&]:block">

Comment: The text seems to be displaying as demonstrated in [this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/TF4gzzRDRb) – this usually indicates some misconfiguration or misuse. Consider providing debugging details about what is making the elements not be visible.

Comment: no,Simply speaking, I want to know the role of peer-[:nth-of-type(3)_&], and I can write a piece of code to demonstrate it

Comment: [this Tailwind Play,why it is hidden](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ORHYXqplqM)

Comment: It is hidden because `display: none` has been applied to the `<div>` element via the `hidden` utility class name.